# Returning objects with internal references

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime

I'm currently working with [rusqlite](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/latest/rusqlite/). I'd like to have an object that implements `Iterator` and returns my application struct, with values constructed from rows in a DB query.

The obvious way would be to wrap a struct around the [`Rows`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/latest/rusqlite/struct.Rows.html) or [`MappedRows`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/latest/rusqlite/struct.MappedRows.html) objects in the rusqlite API. However, each of these types contains a reference to the [`Statement`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/latest/rusqlite/struct.Statement.html) object they derive from, and the `Statement` in turn refers to [`Connection`](https://docs.rs/rusqlite/latest/rusqlite/struct.Connection.html). Thus, assuming a single long-lived `Connection`, the `Statement` object must be preserved for at least the lifetime of any `Rows` object I wrap.

I understand it's not generally allowed to have internal references within an object, due to concerns about it being moved. But the only way I can think of to structure this code is to preserve the `Statement` in the same wrapper I use around the `Rows` object. How can I manage this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the rusqlite doc specifically explains why `Rows` doesn't implement `Iterator` due to exactly those lifetime concerns.

So what you'll want to do is use the statement's `query_map` method:

https://docs.rs/rusqlite/latest/rusqlite/struct.Statement.html#method.query_map

Note that `query_map` returns an iterator over the results of applying a function to the rows returned by the query. So then just pass in a function that constructs an `Application` struct from a row. Just like they do in the example on the main page

```rust
let mut stmt = conn.prepare("SELECT id, name, data FROM person")?;
    let person_iter = stmt.query_map([], |row| {
        Ok(Person {
            id: row.get(0)?,
            name: row.get(1)?,
            data: row.get(2)?,
        })
    })?;
```

In this example your `person_iter` is an iterator over `Person` which itself doesn't actually wrap anything from the sql stuff (that would be poor separation of concerns anyway).

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, this should solve your problem.

EDIT to address the comment:

The first issue (creation of application struct can fail *separately* from rusqlite) can be solved by disentangling things a bit:

In a first step, you'd use `query_map` purely to extract the raw data that will eventually be used in the application struct creation. And then in a second step you'd use *that* iterator to create your application struct object, which now can have any return type you want.

Now for your lifetime issues, if you insist on doing a fully lazy evaluation of your application struct, then, yeah, obviously the connection and everything else related to it needs to be kept alive and I'm not sure what the cleanest way would be for that. You *could* just collect the raw-data iterator into a `Vec` and then wrap *that* in an iterator that will build your application structs.

Comment: Several issues: for one, the `query_map` method seems to demand a function that returns `rusqlite::Error`, but the creation of application structs from DB rows can fail in several ways unrelated to rusqlite, and so I need that function to return my own error type.

Secondly, as far as I can tell, the MappedRows type still has a reference to the Statement, and so I still have the same problem using this function as I do `query` alone.

Comment: Fair points, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Presumably it's possible to keep the Statement alive using some kind of Box or Rc or whatever. But those also don't allow holding open references, due to the possibility of moving. Pin<Box> doesn't seem to work, because it keeps you from getting a mut reference (which you need to execute query or query_map). Is there just no way to do this thing that's completely effortless in a GC language?